# filtering json data by year

Tags: javascript, json, filter

I am looking to filter out records that have a year between 2000 to 2021.

```
"Rank": 50,
   "Title": "Casablanca",
   "Description": "A cynical nightclub owner protects an old flame and her husband from Nazis in Morocco.",
   "Runtime": 102,
   "Genre": "Drama",
   "Rating": 8.5,
   "Metascore": "100",
   "Votes": 441864,
   "Gross_Earning_in_Mil": "1.02",
   "Director": "Michael Curtiz",
   "Actor": "Humphrey Bogart",
   "Year": 1942
```

I have tried using a method I found from a different solution however it does not work correctly.

```
var startDate = new Date("1990");
var endDate = new Date("2000");

var resultProductData = movies.filter(a => {
  var date = new Date(a.Year);
  return (date >= startDate && date <= endDate);
});
```

Comment: `const result = movies.filter(({year}) => (year > 2000 && year < 2021));` The `year` property is an integer, so you can just check it directly.

Comment: The reason your filter isn't working is that you are making the `startDate` and `endDate`  dates from strings and the compare date from an integer. The strings are read as years, while the integer js interprets as milliseconds since epoch time.

Answer (score 2):

Creating Date objects is not gaining you anything here since the year property is already stored as an integer you can just compare it directly

```
const result = movies.filter(({year}) => (year >= 2000 && year =< 2021));
```

But the reason your filter isn't working is that you are creating the `startDate` and `endDate` dates from strings and the compare date from an integer. The strings are interpreted as years, while js interprets the integer as milliseconds since epoch time.

```
var startDate = new Date("1990");
// Mon Jan 01 1990 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT)
var endDate = new Date("2000");
// Sat Jan 01 2000 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT)

const a = { "Year": 1942 }
var date = new Date(a.Year);
// Thu Jan 01 1970 00:00:01 GMT+0000 (GMT)
```

To fix it you would need to cast your `movie.year` to a string.

```
var resultProductData = movies.filter(a => {
  var date = new Date(a.Year.toString());
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thats correct i added the code through mobile missed the string part